# Build and Analyze using xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, build-automation, static-analysis, xcodebuild

Is there a way to do a Build and Analyze like in Xcode using xcodebuild? I'm using Xcode 3.2.2

Answer (score 6):

With Xcode 5, you can simply do `$ xcodebuild [OTHER_OPTIONS] analyze`.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think so, however you can download the Clang Static Analyzer separately, and use it on the command line, for example before your build. The "Build and Analyze" option uses exactly this project to perform the analysis. The output of the Clang analyzer consists in HTML files, which you can automatically store for later review.

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do so now. You can use the "analyze" action.

Example:
`xcodebuild analyze -workspace YourWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme YourSchemeName -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release`

(This is at least as of Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255; however, without taking the time to research, I assume this has been available in previous versions too.)